# Applying a styleClass to a div using a custom css

Tags: html, css, xpages

I have a css (approval.css) defined as a resourceand applied to my XPage. In the css I have this line

```
.appNavBackground {background-color:#ffffd6 ;}
```

in my source I have a div that I apply this styleClass as below:

```
<div class="row" styleClass="appNavBackground">
```

but the styleClass is not applied to the row. I change the row to:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:#ffffd6">
```

and it works fine. If I wrap the div in an xp:panel and select the style from the css it forms fine as well but have the extra panel definition that does nothing but select the styleClass.

what am I missing from the div styleClass definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the HTML div syntax of class with the XPages component syntax of styleClass. So either use HTML only and do this (assuming you want both row and appNavBackground CSS classes applied):

```
<div class="row appNavBackground">
```

Or change it to an XPages component and do this:

```
<xp:div styleClass="row appNavBackground">
```

Comment: So functionally there is no difference between those two statements so long as one recognizes the different syntax? Is there a case where one is preferred?

Comment: If you just need a div, you can go ahead and use the HTML div. But if you want the div to be hidden in certain conditions for instance, you should use xp:div because then you can apply logic to the rendered and loaded properties.

Comment: thanks - so essentially one could mix xp:div and div provided you get the correct </ match without problems.

Comment: Yes, you can mix and match

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code the this.

```
<div class="row appNavBackground">Hello World!</div>
```

Hope this helps.